# Duplicated tags: forensic and forensics. Can we merge them?

Tags: discussion, tagging

It's possibile to merge these two tags? Theyr meaning is the same.

Also: do you think it would be more appropriate to use the long version "computer-forensics"?

Answer (score 1):

They should be merged yes, but only AviD has enough reputation to change tags right now.

I do not think you should use the long version, as it can really be applied to any tag. Just imagine all the overhead on the tags if we are going to have tags similar to computer-security-audit instead of just audit

Comment: I agree on both points. I wanted to create a tag synonym, but it wont let me right now because the nmber of usages is off. In general I prefer synonyms, so we don't have to keep fixing the tags forevermore.

Comment: Update: I proposed a synonym, now its up to you guys to vote it up! `Users with more than 1250 reputation on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.`

Comment: Hmm - I found the list of synonyms here:  http://security.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=all&tab=newest   I don't see where we should vote, and am not clear about the rules.  We have separate answer scores for meta vs security - which one applies?

Comment: @AviD/@nealmcb I have the same problem, I don't see anywhere to vote up a tag proposal.

Comment: @nealmcb, @Graham, in that list you can click on the "master" tag. That will display current and proposed synonyms for the tag, and allow you to vote on the proposed ones (if you have enough score). You can also go to any tag, and click on the `Synonyms` link in the tag header, such as http://security.stackexchange.com/tags/forensics/synonyms.

Comment: @AviD: got it, thanks. I've used my "elite mod skills" to approve the non-controversial synonyms.